# What does "Whena yousa tinkin" mean?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

> Jar Jar Binks: What yet? Monstairs out dare! Leak'n in here, all'n sink'n, and
> nooooo power! You nutsen! WHEN **YOUSA TINK WESA** IN TROUBLE?!!!?

What does "Whena yousa tinkin" mean?

Comment: On most (all?) of your recent questions someone has had to add the [[tag:star-wars]] tag in. When asking questions about anything in the franchise please include this tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the full conversation from the [script at IMSDb](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html) and you can probably work it out:

> **OBI-WAN:** .....we're losing power.
>
> *OBI-WAN is working with the sparking wires. JAR JAR panics.*
>
> **QUI-GON:** Stay calm. We're not in trouble yet.
>
> **JAR JAR:** What yet? Monstairs out dare! Leak'n in here, all'n sink'n, and
> nooooo power! You nutsen! WHEN YOUSA TINK WESA IN TROUBLE?!!!?

He's essentially saying if you don't think we're in trouble now **when will you think we're in trouble?** Because he, himself, surely believes they are in trouble, there's monsters out there and they're leaking and sinking.

Comment: Mesa moui moui grateful forry dis translationee

Answer (score 2):

It means "When do you think". More literally, the words "When are you thinking" are rendered in Jar-Jar's inimitable way of speaking. With that last sentence, he is asking, "When do you think we are in trouble?" as in incredulous way of saying that he thinks they are in trouble and that the others should be concerned.